# Convert native Android to HTML5

Tags: android, html, cross-platform

I have a big Android app with over 20 activities.
Now I have to make it cross-platform and additionally support iOS, Blackberry and Windows.
The app should look the same on all platforms and the GUI developed only once.

Is it possible to automatically convert Android XML layouts to HTML+CSS ?
What IDE are good for working with PhoneGapp / Cordova, HTML, CSS, Javascript ?

Thanks!

Comment: "The app should look the same on all platforms" IMHO that's a very bad design. The platforms are different and their individualities should be taken into account.

Comment: No it's not possible to auto-magically convert android XML layouts to HTML. You'll have to do it manually if you want it converted. But please bear in mind what Budius said, all of the platforms are different by using the exact same layout/look and feel in all of them you will be breaking best practices for many of them.

Answer (score 0):

No Hello_World,you cannot convert the Android XML directly to HTML/CSS. you need to code everything separately. you can take the help of DREAMWEAVER for HTML and CSS.

For java script you can use WEB STORM IDE-(well,i haven't used this...,but found and read its useful).

For phone gap Eclipse-is good.but you will not be getting any sort of prompts for the java script coding.That is why i suggest WEB STORM IDE, because it kills your time to find out the minor mistakes..such as not closing the tag,extra apostrophe...etc...etc..

Comment: Actually it is possible. But you'd have to build your own converter.

Comment: Some have tried it too
https://github.com/RonaldDomo/Android-layouts-for-HTML